# Changing number of bootstrap rows based on viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am newer to Bootstrap 3 and was having trouble with something.

I have a row of 5 images that is defined by this:

```
  .callout {
         .make-sm-column(2.4);
  }
```

And on mobile, I would like those 5 columns, to be split into a row of 2 images, followed by a second row of the last 3 images.  My understanding of the grid system was that if that a column / element didn't fit inside a pre-defined row, it would automatically be bumped to the next "line".

Based on this understanding, I thought I could apply this:

```
        .callout {
            &:nth-child(-n+2)
            {
                .make-xs-column(6);
            }
            &:nth-child(n+3)
            {
                .make-xs-column(4);
            }
         }
```

What I'm seeing though, is the first 2 images are own their own row like I expected, but the next image sits by itself positioned to the right on it's own row and then the last 2 images are on their own row positioned to the left.

Comment: To clarify my earlier questions, I'm confused by your implementation of `2.4` for the column width. I wasn't aware that you could do that. What's the resulting CSS output?

Comment: @isherwood the resulting output applies `float: left;`
    `width: 20%;` `padding-left: 15px;` `padding-right: 15px;` on the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the column to wrap to a new row properly on the XS viewport by clearing the left float on the 3rd column.

**New CSS**

```
         .callout {
            padding: 10px 15px;
                &:nth-child(1)
                {
                    .make-xs-column-offset(1);
                }
                &:nth-child(-n+2){
                    .make-xs-column(5);
                }
                &:nth-child(3)
                {
                    clear: left;
                }
                &:nth-child(n+3)
                {
                    .make-xs-column(4);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

the beauty of the bootstrap grid system is that you can just use their `col` size assignments to do what you want to accomplish. demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/440/ (adjust the width of the results screen)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 img col-sm-6 col-xs-6">img 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 img col-sm-6 col-xs-6">img 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 img col-sm-4 col-xs-4">img 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 img col-sm-4 col-xs-4">img 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 img col-sm-4 col-xs-4">img 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to create a uniform 5-column layout for larger screens.

Comment: @isherwood, ahh, yes thanks for that, i added `col-md-offset-#` to make it more uniform

Comment: A good solution, but it doesn't use the whole screen. We'll have to see what OP thinks. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4gtbh0c4/

Comment: @isherwood ahh yes, cause the 12 col grid sadly isnt evenly divisible by 5. im quite interested if there's a solution that would be able to use boostraps grid to utilize the full screen in such situations without heavy modifications. i think it would be very useful to myself and the general dev community

Comment: It appears that the OP is doing so with `2.4` as a column width in the LESS code. I'm not familiar enough with that approach to know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution.  I was also able to fix the problem by clearing the left float on the 3rd image.

Comment: @user3267755: were you able to utilze the full screen using the 2.4 implementation? id be interested in seeing that solution (and im sure others would be too) - if you have time to post, of course.

Comment: @indubitablee I would be happy to.  What exactly would you like to see?  I have 5 callouts / images that are equal width / responsive across my container on the page

Comment: @user3267755 ahh, interesting, i didnt know they added a less "mixins" section in bootstrap haha, havent revisited the documentation in a while. so you defined the column width in relation to the original 12 column division. awesome implementation! you should probably post that and accept your own answer since its the correct one in relation to your question (and it'll be easier for users having similar issues to find the solution easier vs reading through the comments :p)

Comment: @indubitablee here is a puush image of my console / less / screen utilizing the full width (I turned off the containers width so that it would stretch) - http://puu.sh/loRBp/93887c1741.jpg